# GIMP Filter in C#

Tags: c#, filter, path, external, gimp

I'm trying all day long to get this code run, but no chance. I would like to execute a GIMP filter on an image and save it later to a certain path. With this code:

```
string choosenFile = "D:\\here\\is\\the\\image";
string gimpFile = "D:\\here\\is\\my\\gimp exe";



void seamlessFilter() {
    try {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(choosenFile)) {
            string a = @"-b ""(script-fu-tile \""" 
            + choosenFile
            + "100 100 0 TRUE 70"  
            + @")"" -b ""(gimp-quit 0)""";
            string result = ExecuteCommandSync(a);
            Texture2D newTex = loadImage (new Vector2(200, 200), Path.GetFullPath(choosenFile));
            newTex = null;
        } else {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Please select a image");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log (ex.ToString ());
    }
}

public string ExecuteCommandSync(string command) {
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo (gimpFile, command);
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process process = new Process ();
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;

    process.Start ();
    StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    Console.WriteLine (result);
    return result;
}
```

I try to execute the filter, but I get every time an error, that the string couldn't be read. 
Here is the .scm:

```
 `
(define (script-fu-tile img 
        drawable 
        blend-x 
        blend-y 
        overlap 
        square)

(let*

    (

    (sel-float1 0)

    (sel-float2 0)

    (sel-float3 0)
    (sel-float4 0)
    (high-pass-layer 0)

    (yoffset 0)

    (img-w (/ (car (gimp-image-width img)) 2))

    (img-h (/ (car (gimp-image-height img)) 2))

;(newimg (car (gimp-image-new (- (car (gimp-image-width img)) blend-x) 
(- (car (gimp-image-height img)) blend-y) RGB)))

    )

    (if (= square 1)

        (set! yoffset (+ (- (* (- img-w img-h) 2) (- blend-x blend-y)) overlap))

        (set! yoffset overlap)

    )


    (gimp-undo-push-group-start img)


    (gimp-rect-select img 0 0 img-w img-h CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE FALSE 0)


    (gimp-edit-copy drawable)

    (set! sel-float1 (car (gimp-edit-paste drawable FALSE)))

    (gimp-floating-sel-to-layer sel-float1)

    (gimp-layer-translate sel-float1 (- (- img-w blend-x) yoffset) (- (- img-h blend-y) overlap))


    (gimp-rect-select img img-w 0 img-w img-h CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE FALSE 0)


    (gimp-edit-copy drawable)

    (set! sel-float2 (car (gimp-edit-paste drawable FALSE)))
    (gimp-floating-sel-to-layer sel-float2)

    (gimp-layer-translate sel-float2 (- 0 img-w) (- (- img-h blend-y) overlap))


    (gimp-rect-select img 0 img-h img-w img-h CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE FALSE 0)


    (gimp-edit-copy drawable)

    (set! sel-float3 (car (gimp-edit-paste drawable FALSE)))

    (gimp-floating-sel-to-layer sel-float3)

    (gimp-layer-translate sel-float3 (- (- img-w blend-x) yoffset) (- 0 img-h))


    (gimp-rect-select img img-w img-h img-w img-h CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE FALSE 0)


    (gimp-edit-copy drawable)

    (set! sel-float4 (car (gimp-edit-paste drawable FALSE)))

    (gimp-floating-sel-to-layer sel-float4)

    (gimp-layer-translate sel-float4 (- 0 img-w) (- 0 img-h))


    (gimp-rect-select img (- 0 blend-x) (- 0 blend-x) (+ img-w (/ blend-x 2)) (+ img-h (+ blend-x blend-x)) CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE TRUE (/ blend-x 1.68))

    (gimp-selection-invert img)

    (gimp-edit-clear sel-float4)


    (gimp-rect-select img (- 0 blend-y) (- 0 blend-y) (+ img-w (+ blend-y blend-y)) (+ img-h (/ blend-y 2)) CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE TRUE (/ blend-y 1.68))

    (gimp-selection-invert img)

    (gimp-edit-clear sel-float4)


    (gimp-rect-select img (- (- img-w (- blend-x blend-y)) yoffset) (- 0 blend-y) (+ img-w (+ blend-y blend-y)) (+ img-h (/ blend-y 2)) CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE TRUE (/ blend-y 1.68))

    (gimp-selection-invert img)

    (gimp-edit-clear sel-float3)


    (gimp-rect-select img (- 0 blend-x) (- (- img-h (+ blend-x blend-y)) overlap) (+ img-w (/ blend-x 2)) (+ img-h (+ blend-x blend-x)) CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE TRUE (/ blend-x 1.68))

    (gimp-selection-invert img)

    (gimp-edit-clear sel-float2)


    (gimp-selection-none img)


    ;(gimp-layer-delete drawable)


    (gimp-image-crop img (- (- (* img-w 2) blend-x) yoffset) (- (- (* img-h 2) blend-y) overlap) 0 0)





    ; Complete the undo group

    (gimp-undo-push-group-end img)


    ; Flush output

    (gimp-displays-flush)

)
)




 (script-fu-register "script-fu-tile"

  "<Image>/Filters/Map/Tileable..."

  "Make seamless texture"

  "Pavel aka RPG Roshchin <rpg89@post.ru>"

  "Pavel aka RPG Roshchin"

  "2011"

  "RGB*, GRAY*"

   SF-IMAGE "Image" 0

   SF-DRAWABLE "Layer to blur" 0

   SF-ADJUSTMENT "Blend x" '(100 0 1000 1 10 0 0)

   SF-ADJUSTMENT "Blend y" '(100 0 1000 1 10 0 0)

   SF-ADJUSTMENT "Overlap" '(0 0 1000 1 10 0 0)

   SF-TOGGLE
    "Make square texture"   TRUE

   ;SF-ADJUSTMENT "Homogenize brightness (%)" '(70 0 100 1 10 0 0)

   )`
```

I'd be so glade if anyone could help, because I despair. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out at my own - the problem was, that the first argument img expects an object but I wrote a string as the first argument. So I edited my scm script to wrap a object as a string and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go and have a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/332376/Execute-Gimp-filters-in-Csharp) and give this method a try

But by the looks of things your:

```
 string a = @"-b ""(script-fu-tile \""" 
        + choosenFile
        + "100 100 0 TRUE 70"  
        + @")"" -b ""(gimp-quit 0)""";
```

Should look more like this:

```
string a = @"gimp-2.6.exe -i -b ""(script-fu-tile \""" +
               choosenFile + @"\""0 100 100 0 TRUE 70)"" -b ""(gimp-quit 0)""";
```

Or Essentially:

```
    string draw = "0";
    string blendx = "100";
    string blendy = "100";
    string overlap = "0";
    string sqrText = "TRUE";
    string adjBright = "70";
    string a = @"gimp-2.6.exe -i -b ""(simple-unsharp-mask \""" +
              path + @"\"" " + draw + " " + blendx + " " + blendy + " " + overlap + " "+ sqrText + " " + adjBright +
              @")"" -b ""(gimp-quit 0)""";
```

By the looks of what the error is saying that you have provided there is a problem with the above string in your code. Give those few a try and comment back to me.

Comment: Updated again. Give that a try.

Comment: Now I get that error:
`Error: ( : 1) Invalid type for argument 1 to gimp-image-width`

Comment: Better split the whole thing in manageable problems. So 1) check that the SCM works inside Gimp, 2) figure out the whole incantation to call it from a command line and 3) make a C# that calls said command line. Btw I don't know C# but I'm ready to bet that when you use `UseShellExecute=False` the parameters to the command should be a list of strings that correspond to the individual parameters and not a big string that lumps them all together.

Comment: the .scm works fine in GIMP. 
Don't really understand where the issue with using `UseShellExecute=False` is?